# Oracle - ORA-00903: invalid table name

Tags: oracle

I am unable to find the error with this statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE "FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES_RARF_ORIG"
  ( "ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CODE" CHAR(2) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(32), 
    "CREATED" DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATED" DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
                    USING INDEX (create unique index "UX_FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES" on "FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES" ("ID")));
```

It's failing with error `ORA-00903: invalid table name`.

Where is the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using modified DDL from an existing table. You've changed the table name, from `FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES` to `FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES_RARF_ORIG`; but you didn't change the reference to it in the index:

```
(create unique index "UX_FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES" on "FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES" ("ID"))
```

should be

```
(create unique index "UX_FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES" on "FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES_RARF_ORIG" ("ID"))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=60eabd4bf8a4c9f2d003bd73232dcb87)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it..

I had a different table name in the using index (create unique index  `"UX_FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES"` on `"FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES" ("ID"));`

IT should be (create unique index  `"UX_FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES"` on `"FUEL_TRANSPORTATION_TYPES_RARF_ORIG" ("ID"));`